# How do I set up my machine to process transactions and earn the transaction fees?

Tags: transaction-fees

I am unable to earn money from solving blocks, but I think I could make money from transaction fees. The issue is that pools hide the transaction fees from the miners. The miners earn the solved blocks. How would I go about processing transactions on my own?

This will satisfy two goals:

1. earn transaction fees
2. any transactions I perform, I can process myself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to collect money from transaction fees is to solve blocks; they are one and the same thing. The reward for being the first to successfully mine a block is:

- the coinbase reward (currently 25 BTC), and
- any transaction fees for the transactions included in the block

There is no way to separate these two.

Comment: I believe that is incorrect because that would imply that we cannot process transactions after running out of coins. As a result, they must be separate components. Unless, it's the value of each block that is being halved, not the computational complexity of each block being doubled (my assumption is the later because we increase the number of leading zeros on the proof of work).

Comment: No, that doesn't imply such a thing at all. After the coinbase reward reaches zero in 2140 or whatever, the only reward miners will receive is the transaction fee component. The complexity of the mining transaction (the so-called "difficulty") is adjusted up OR down every two weeks to match the network performance, independent of the predetermined coinbase reward reduction schedule.

Comment: It looks like my assumption, required for my reasoning to follow does not hold. The reason we run of out coins is because the value of mining a block is reduced over time: ( https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Controlled_supply ) not because it becomes more computationally difficult. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer is:** You still have to mine a block, the transaction fee is added to the block reward.

**The detailed answer:** The idea of transaction fees is to **supply miners with enough BTCs** so the can keep on mining blocks. Because we keep all transactions on the block chain, it's important for the BTC ecosystem to have a big miner community. Eventually the prize for solving a block will drop, but the number of transactions will increase in such a way, it'll add sufficient number of BTCs to the miners.

After a point, BTC price will hopefully high enough to give miners a incentive to continue mining.