# Can I earn transaction fees by running as a full node, verifying transactions, but not mining?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, nodes

As I understand it, by running a full node (i.e. Bitcoin-QT) , I am helping confirm transactions and contributing to the Bitcoin network.

When transaction fees are offered, do I receive these, and if so, how? Or do I need to be a fully fledged miner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up my machine to process transactions and earn the transaction fees?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21631/how-do-i-set-up-my-machine-to-process-transactions-and-earn-the-transaction-fees)

Answer (score 11):

Nope, transaction fees of a transaction can only be collected by including it into a valid block. And to be able to include a transaction in a valid block you have to mine a valid block.

Answer (score 6):

While running Bitcoin-qt it is true you are contributing to the Bitcoin network, but only in the sense that other peers can now download the blockchain using your bandwidth.  There are no transaction fees sent to anyone that is not mining.  Mining is the process which helps the network transact and thus sending balances from one account to another.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnodes has just launched their [incentive program](https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/nodes/incentive/). Every week they randomly select one node out of a pool of eligible nodes who receives a small incentive (~10-30USD). Besides that you will not receive any Bitcoins by just running a full node.

Comment: The link is broken